# Getting rid of the top region above a NavigationView (solutions on Stack Overflow not working)

Tags: swiftui

I need to have a search box on the view but I don't want that ridiculous space at the top (see picture):

[image]

Normally I would use the modifiers

```
.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

Both do nothing.

Here is an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var searchText = ""

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        NavigationLink(destination: Color(.red) ) {
          Text("aaa")
        }
        NavigationLink(destination: Color(.red) ) {
          Text("bbb")
        }
        NavigationLink(destination: Color(.red) ) {
          Text("ccc")
        }
      }
    }
    .searchable(text: $searchText, prompt: "search...")
    .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
}
```

Any other options?

NOTE: I am talking about the yellow region. I want to get rid of it.

Comment: This needs a [mre]. You likely have multiple navigation bars or something like that.

Comment: added an example

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue happening in your example.

Comment: jnpdx - he is talking about the WTH?? part at the top thats a huge gap at the top.

Comment: @easleyfixed Yes -- I understand that. The issue is not represented in the code when I run it.

Comment: Ahh i get you, you don't see it in the code, not just visually, gotcha, sorry my bad ;/  For whats its worth, me either.

Comment: yes, I am talking about the WTH region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move the `.navigationBarHidden(true)` to the list:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: Color(.red) ) {
                    Text("aaa")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Color(.red) ) {
                    Text("bbb")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Color(.red) ) {
                    Text("ccc")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText, prompt: "search...")
    }
}
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbarhidden(_:)):

> This modifier only takes effect when the modified view is **inside of** and **visible** within a NavigationView.

**NOTE**: `navigationBarHidden(_:)` will be deprecated in iOS 16. It will be replaced by [`toolbar(_:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/toolbar(_:for:)).